# Why Externalizable when read/writeObject method are there in serializable

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, externalizable

I am not able to clear this confusion of mine,

Externalizable is used because we can give our own (more efficient) implementation of serialization-deserialization using read/writeExternal method. And control the serialization process.

We can also use read/writeObject method and serialization process will be overridden with that.

Then why is Externalizable even required?

Why would someone prefer read/writeExternal over read/writeObject?

Comment: How exactly would you override serialization process with `readObject` or `writeObject`?

Comment: As per my understanding, we can give our own implementation of serialization process in readObject and java will call readObject method if it is present instead of using its own implementaion. Similarly for writeObject.

Comment: So you would implement a custom `ObjectOutputStream` or `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: The default ObjectStream will be used

Answer (score 1):

Just the customization in case of serialization.

The reason is given in [Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) docs

> The writeExternal and readExternal methods of the Externalizable interface are implemented by a class to give the class complete control over the format and contents of the stream for an object and its supertypes. These methods must explicitly coordinate with the supertype to save its state. **These methods supersede customized implementations of writeObject and readObject methods.**
>   Object Serialization uses the Serializable and Externalizable interfaces. Object persistence mechanisms can use them as well. Each object to be stored is tested for the Externalizable interface. If the object supports Externalizable, the writeExternal method is called. If the object does not support Externalizable and does implement Serializable, the object is saved using ObjectOutputStream. **

Comment: But all these control and customization can be achieved by read/writeObject as well. What extra Externalizable is giving?

Comment: @RahulTyagi Assume that you need to save your Object to a file and at the same time you have to have a custom serialization ? In that case, writeExternal will be used for serialization and writeObject for writing your object to file.

Comment: But only writeObject could work for both, isn't it?

Comment: Could work if you do not implement Externalizable and no further customization required while serializing.

Comment: That is the question, if externalizable interface were not even exist what would have we missed? We could achieve everything using read/write Object method.

Comment: Again, if you want to have separate implementation just for serialization and not for any other purpose, you use externalizable  interface and *external methods.